# Find a string in name and move at the of the of the name before the extension

Tags: rename

i have many files in different subdir.
I would like to rename all files named 
`*-ABC-DE(7 numbers).ext`
to 
`*-DE(7 numbers)-ABC.ext`

Is it possible?

Comment: Please give some actual examples - `(7 numbers)` is ambiguous

Comment: It a string of 7 characters.
It could be DE1234567 or  DE7654321

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
$ ls *.ext
bar-ABC-DE7654321.ext  foo-ABC-DE1234567.ext
```

then

```
$ rename -v 's/(ABC)-(DE\d{7})/$2-$1/' *.ext
rename(bar-ABC-DE7654321.ext, bar-DE7654321-ABC.ext)
rename(foo-ABC-DE1234567.ext, foo-DE1234567-ABC.ext)
```

resulting in

```
$ ls *.ext
bar-DE7654321-ABC.ext  foo-DE1234567-ABC.ext
```

**NB test with `-n` first**

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. It work as i wanted to. tnx